# cannot initialise type xy Does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
public Response GetDate(Request request)
{
    Details details = new Details();
    Response response = new Response
    {
        details.GetAction(request.CreationDate,request.LineOfBusiness,request.DocumentCategory,request.TransactionFlow,request.BundleName),
    };
    return response;
}
```

and the class has

```
[DataContract]
public class Request
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string LineOfBusiness { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string DocumentCategory { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string TransactionFlow { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string BundleName { get; set; }
}
```

And I am getting error that collection is not implementing `System.Collections.IEnumerable`. I checked other similar questions. But I am not using any LINQ.

Comment: Which line does give the error? I suspect it's here: `Response response = new Response
    {
        details.GetAction(request.CreationDate,request.LineOfBusiness,request.DocumentCategory,request.TransactionFlow,request.BundleName),
    };` Since that error occurs mostly when you're initialising an instance of a class directly in a wrong way. If this is the line, you could take a look at the way you're doing it according to the structure of tha `Response` class.

Comment: ya in the line which you mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is syntax of collection initializer.

```
Response response = new Response
{
    details.GetAction(...),
};
```

Response is object.

You probably want to call the Response constructor.

```
new Response(...);
```

Or to use object initializer which is syntax is:

```
new Response {Property = Value}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the collection initializer syntax for the `Response` object, but it doesn't implement `IEnumerable`.

Either, you didn't intend use the collection intitializer syntax and you meant to use the object intitializer syntax like so:

```
Response response = new Response
{
    SomeProperty= details.GetAction(request.CreationDate,request.LineOfBusiness,request.DocumentCategory,request.TransactionFlow,request.BundleName)
};
```

Or, you need to implement `IEnumerable` and an `Add` method on your `Response` object.